# Blueimp query file uploader output jpg only

Tags: php, blueimp

I'm using the blueimp jquery file upload script from github: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload. It is a really good script, but it also reminds me how much I hate classes, and especially after jquery uploads. 
That being said (frustration!), can anyone point me in the right direction for uploading and always outputting as jpg.

Image conversion is still like magic to me, but I found this piece of code on their github:

```
$dst_type = ($extention == 'jpg') ? 'jpeg' : $extention;
$write_image = 'image'.$dst_type;
        $success = imagecopyresampled(
            $new_img,
            $src_img,
            $dst_x,
            $dst_y,
            0,
            0,
            $new_width,
            $new_height,
            $img_width,
            $img_height
        ) && $write_image($new_img, $new_file_path, $image_quality);
```

The first two lines are supposed to work, but the file size is still the same and so is the file name output. So it doesn't work. 
Now the file name output doesn't bother me seeing I'm changing it after the upload and DB input anyways. But the file size is a real problem when uploading png's. I'd like it all to jpg's. The file in question is this one: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/server/php/UploadHandler.php

So, convert all uploaded to jpg's. All input is, as always, appreciated.